# how execute SSIS Package on SQL Server 2005 in javascript code?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ssis

I need to execute an SSIS Package on SQL Server 2005 but programing them using the javasript code for a page web.

Anybody can help me please??

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a site to solicit people to do work for you. It's a question and answer site, meaning the answer will appear here, and you'll have to read it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript executing in a web page is executing in a client's browser. It can't directly call any code on the server.

You will need to create a web service, and have the page ask the service to execute the SSIS package. How to do that is beyond the scope of a single question. You'll want to learn how to use AJAX to call a web service, and how to execute an SSIS package from code (a web service, in this case).

---

More importantly, why do you have to do this with JavaScript? Why not do it in the codebehind, as part of a button click handler (as one example)?

Comment: OLGA is talking about ASP.NET here, so no, this does not apply.

Comment: Hrmm I know theres server side javascript (SSJS) ... never played around with it though (and dont plan on it lol)... would it be possible with that? Granted I would never do this.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client-side language (and should stay that way!). You cannot run statements against a database from JavaScript.  You need a server-side language for this (ASP.NET, PHP, or the like), or a web service for JavaScript to ping to kick it off.

Once you determine that, though, you can use [`sp_start_job`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260289(SQL.80).aspx) to kick off a SQL Server Agent job that in turn kicks off the SSIS package for you. Or, you can use an `exec` command (depending on the language you use), and you can use the [`dtexec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx) utility to directly start the package.

Comment: Of course I have a web service page where I'm working in ASP.NET and I prefer to use javascript language for a functions and the others routine like this, but I don't have any idea how to do it!
Nom you understand me?